# Characterizing a circle.

Tags: geometry, definition

Is it correct to **characterize a circle** by saying that *it is a closed curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that all points on the curve are equidistant from a single fixed point?*

I am familiar with shapes such as reuleaux polygons, so this isn't what I am getting at (that is shapes of constant width).

My gut feeling tells me that one can construct a (convoluted) curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with this property that wouldn't be geometrically (or even topologically) a circle. I particularly would like to stick with closed curves in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and comparing them with $S^1$. I am sure this question might have different answers for higher dimensions, but I am not concerned with these.

I mean formally we would write down that the circle is $S^1 = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \, | \, x^2 + y^2 = r \}$, but does this bi-conditionally translate to my first statement?

**Edit to this original question:** The way I phrased the question was poor in hindsight partly because I hadn't quite pinned down what exactly what I wanted to ask. The more precise statement I am trying to make is the following,

*For the metric space $(\mathbb{R}^2 , d)$ where $d$ is the standard Euclidean metric, we define the circle centered at the point $(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ to be the set $S^1 = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \, | \, (x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 = r^2 \}$, where we say that $r$ is the radius of the circle. Is this definition equivalent to saying a circle is a closed curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that all points on the curve are equidistant from a single fixed point? I do not care for the single point to be the origin and the distant to be $r$*

Again, my gut feeling says that one might be able to construct a (convoluted) curve that has this property which is not the same realization as $S^1$.

Comment: If in the first statement you consider the distance to be $\sqrt r$ and the fixed point to be the origin, then yes, it does.

Comment: It does not have to be the origin. I see how the statements are equivalent if this condition is added.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is just notation; say that the distance to the given point is $r$, and that the point is $(c_1, c_2)$. Then you're just asking that, for points $(x,y)$ on the curve, $d((x,y),(c_1,c_2)) = r$; writing down the formula for $d$ gives $\{(x, y) \in \mathbb R^2 | (x-c_1)^2 + (y-c_2)^2 = r\}$.

Comment: If by "characterize" you mean "provides an alternative definition" you need to tell us what other definition you have in mind. If by "characterize" you mean "define" then we need to stop and say that definitions can't really be correct or not. Personally I think "set of points at a fixed distance from a fixed point (using some distance function)" is the most basic definition of circle that you can use.

Comment: Seconding rschwieb's concern (from his answer). You have not told us what you mean by *a closed curve*? If you traverse a semicircle back and forth is that a closed curve? According to some definition it might be, but you probably mean that a closed curve is a function $\gamma$ from $[0,1]$ to $\Bbb{R}^2$ such that $\gamma(t)=(x(t),y(t))$ has the properties that $x$ and $y$ are continuos and that for $t_1\neq t_2$ it is possible that $\gamma(t_1)=\gamma(t_2)$ if and only if $\{t_1,t_2\}=\{0,1\}$. Or something like that.

Comment: Maybe that was naive of me to use that terminology. What I intended to mean was that if you traverse the curve (continuously, I guess) in one direction you return to the starting point. Self crossing I guess can be allowed (I am not quite sure what restricting this would do.

Comment: That's ok. Defining what a curve is, is one of those questions that takes many vector calculus students by surprise. "You mean it's not clear!?" That's one of the reasons why teachers keep throwing patological objects like Peano curves at the students :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A circle is the *set* of *all* points of distance $r$ from a certain point (its centre). If you have *a* closed curve such that all points are equidistant from a fixed centre, this (or rather its image) may not be a circle. For example, consider the closed curve $[0,2\pi]\to\mathbb R^2$, $t\mapsto (\sin\sin t,\cos\sin t)$, which merely goes back and forth on some arc of the unit circle.

If you add the condition that the curve be *simple*, you are fine, though (modulo distinction between curve and image of curve): By the distance condition, your curve is an continuous, injective map (apart from the end points) essentially into a circle and must be onto (and in fact a homeomorphism). This follows from investigating all continuous maps $S^1\to S^1$ and homotopy.

Comment: I like the answer, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, given a topological metric space $(X,d)$ and a point $a\in X$ and $r\in \Bbb R^+$, a circle $(C,a,r)$ is *defined* as to be $\{b\in X\mid d(a,b)=r\}$.

Since for any real number $r>0$ we have $x^2+y^2=r\iff \sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\sqrt{r}$, it turns out the set you're defining is just a circle in the Euclidean metric about the origin. Of course the set for a circle about the point $(h,k)$ is just $\{(x,y)\mid d((x,y),(h,k))=\sqrt{(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2}=\sqrt{r}\}$.

There are other metrics on $\Bbb R^2$, though. I would invite you to consider what the unit circles for the following metrics would look like:

1. $d((x,y),(w,z))=|x-w|+|y-z|$
2. $d((x,y),(w,z))=\max(|x-w|,|y-z|)$

---

There are probably other characterizations of circles, but I can't think of any less complicated than the one using a distance function at the moment.

---

(Added after new edits)

> For the metric space $(\mathbb{R}^2 , d)$ where $d$ is the standard Euclidean metric, we define the circle centered at the point $(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ to be the set $S^1 = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \, | \, (x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 = r^2 \}$, where we say that $r$ is the radius of the circle. Is this definition equivalent to saying a circle is a closed curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that all points on the curve are equidistant from a single fixed point?

In $\Bbb R^2$ they are virtually identical ("all points at a fixed distance from a fixed point") except that the one you are suggesting has "and the set is a closed curve" tacked on, which is a property of the set in question and doesn't really have to be part of its definition.

In the Euclidean distance, $d(a,b)=r \iff d(a,b)^2=r^2$, so the fact that the square root is missing inside the set you mentioned is inessential.

Comment: I have done the exercise you suggested before. I am not worried about abstraction to different metrics on $\mathbb{R}^2$. I have tried to edit my original question to clarify the idea I had. Please read it and suggest if I am making sense or not. I am having a hard time precisely articulating the idea I am having. It is kind of like how people thought that the only geometric shape with the property of constant width was the circle, then the reuleaux polygons were realized. Where as if no other geometric shapes with this property existed, we could define the circle by this property.

Comment: @o0BlueBeast0o Ah, I have never heard of that possible definition. I thought the geometric version had been used since Euclid. I tried to add more based on your edits to the question.

Comment: I apologize for being unclear earlier. If I could accept both answers I would. Thank you for the time.